# Create a signal that emits one object then completes?

Tags: reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

With RxSwift, I would do `Observable.just(1)` which will emit `1` then emit completed.

It looks like with RAC2 you could do: `[RACSignal return:@1]`

How do I do that with RAC3?

To be more clear... I'm looking for a way to create a RAC3 `Signal` that produces a single hard-coded value. How would I do that? (`SignalProducer(value: 1)` doesn't work that way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the discussion, I think the answer by Charlotte Tortorella stands correct: you achieve the required behavior with `SignalProducer(value: 1`).

I think the problem is a miss understanding about what `Signal` and `SignalProducer` are.

[As described here](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift#signals-and-signalproducers-hot-and-cold-observables), a `Signal` in ReactiveSwift is a **hot** `RACSignal` in RAC 2.0 or `Observable` in Rx, and a `SignalProducer` in ReactiveSwift is a **cold** `RACSignal` in RAC 2.0 or `Observable` in Rx. This is deliberate deviation from other reactive frameworks as well as from RAC < 3.0.

This means, you most likely have a method that takes a **cold** `RACSignal` or `Observable` since you want it to fire for every subscriber.

So if you want to convert your RAC 2.0 code, that expects a **cold** `Signal` or `Observable`, you will need to change it to take a `SignalProducer` in RAC >= 3.0.

As an illustration take this example in ObjC and RAC 2.0:

```
-(void)observeSignal:(RACSignal *)signal
{
    [signal subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *x) {
        NSLog(@"Next: %@", x);
    } completed:^{
        NSLog(@"Completed");
    }];
}
```

Calling this method like this

```
RACSignal *signal = [RACSignal return:@(1)];
[self observeSignal:signal];
[self observeSignal:signal];
```

(twice for illustration of the behaviour on each subscription) will print

```
Next: 1
Completed
Next: 1
Completed
```

In Swift and with ReactiveCocoa 5.0, an equivalent implementation could look like this

```
func observe(produer: SignalProducer<Int, NoError>) {
    produer.start { event in
        switch event {
        case .value(let value):
            print("Next: \(value)")
        case .completed:
            print("Completed")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Called like this

```
let producer = SignalProducer<Int, NoError>(value: 1)
observe(produer: producer)
observe(produer: producer)
```

it produces the same output

```
Next: 1
Completed
Next: 1
Completed
```

The swift version might look a bit bulkier, but if you only need the `Next`/`value` Events they look more or less the same. Note, that you'll need to `start` the producer instead of just `observe` the signal.

So in conclusion:

You are correct, theres no way to provide an equivalent if you expect a `Signal`. For an equivalent implementation, you will need to change your function to take a `SignalProducer`. `SignalProducer` is equivalent to a **cold** `Signal` which will fire for **each** subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

RAC 3 and up uses a constructor.

`SignalProducer(value: 1)`

Comment: But how do you pass it to a function that takes a Signal?

Comment: You don't. Signals fire immediately so by the time your function inspected the Signal you passed in, it'd be completed and the value would be lost.

Comment: So it's not equivalent to the RxSwift and RAC2 examples I gave which will fire once for every subscriber. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, SignalProducers are the ones that fire once for every subscriber. Signals do not. My answer is equivalent to your examples.

Comment: But you can't pass it to a function that expects a Signal? In that case your answer isn't equivalent.

Comment: Signals and SignalProducers are two different things. If a function wants a Signal then it probably wants a stream of values that'll never end. The API changed and isn't 1:1 equivalent to RAC 2 anymore.